# How to copy with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i copy 1 div element with 3 child elements in it,for like 12 times with javascript.Here is what i have done and it isn't working...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 for (var i=1;i<12;i++){
      document.getElementByClassName("food-content").innerHTML += 
     "<div class='food-group'><a>Link " + i + "</a></div>";
 }
 
});
```

And here is my HTML elements which i want to copy.

```css
<div class="food-col1">
<div class="food-group">
<a>Убвец!<img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/4b52e3e1db8f43cfb2f7c9829f4bebde.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no function `getElementByClassName`, only `getElementsByClassName` which will return an array, so you'd need:

`document.getElementsByClassName("food-content")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: It isn't working ;/ im hopeless

Comment: Please show your updated code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ldv2RKNZ
Sorry don't know how to add code to comment lol..

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGBBZK Works completely fine for me.

Comment: It isn't working in my page here is what i tried.(working on wordpress)
1.Connect my file with <script> tag and enter code right under html elements.
2.Connect it with php code to my HTML file.
3.Writed a new .js file and included it in html.
4.Cleared cache.
Nothing works ;/

Comment: There is example of what i am trying to do:http://prntscr.com/dhqh68 (its a table with div elements)
There is what i have at the moment:http://prntscr.com/dhqhlw Haven't worked on style ,i wanna copy it first.